# Does ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList vulnerable to OS Command Injection?

Tags: .net, security

There is some C# code (.NET Core 3.1 platform):

```
        var userInput = "8.8.8.8";
        var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        var info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ping",
        };
        info.ArgumentList.Add(userInput);
        info.ArgumentList.Add("-n");
        info.ArgumentList.Add("8");
        process.StartInfo = info;
        process.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Is it possible to create user input (**modify userInput variable**) such to modify the PING-tool behaviour (eg, inject the "-w 999999" argument)?

Comment: Well, try it and tell us ?

Comment: Validating user input is useful for multiple reasons, for one you want to display a good error message.  Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: @HansPassant, yep, user input has to be validated, however, this is an example. In my case, I have to pass a password in arguments for other OS command, and the password hasn't to be limited in charset at all.

Comment: Posting an irrelevant example is not wise.  You can validate a password as well, it won't contain a space.  In the unlikely case that it does, you can demand that the user delimits it with, say, double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create user input such to modify the PING-tool behaviour (eg, inject the "-w 999999" argument)?

yes

> Does ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList vulnerable to OS Command Injection?

It's intended. So yes but I don't think it's a problem. Starting a tool with arguments is what is expected right?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely my question was misunderstood.
I wanted to know if OS Command injection can be performed if the "userInput" variable will be other.
My answer is that most likely not, because in the depths of net core, process arguments are double-quoted, and all occurrences of quotes in an argument are double-escaped.

Please correct if I'm wrong.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/PasteArguments.cs